# How to create JProgressBar for executeUpdate()

Tags: java, prepared-statement, teradata, jprogressbar

My little application uploads table to a database .

```
Connection ....   
   ... 
   ...
PreparedStatement ps  ... 
ps.executeUpdate() ; // this takes a while so I want to create a progress bar
```

How can I track progress  of  `ps.executeUpdate()` ?  Can anybody post a java code to do that ?  I need to create a **progress bar**

(My database is Teradata)

Comment: The logs of your database.

Comment: Thank you. Could you post any java code to get the log data ?

Comment: This is not possible. The database doesn't tell you how far it is.

Comment: On this forum http://www.javakey.net/4-java-gui/f20262e7348dcbcf.htm one says it is not possible another says it is possible

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities to display "something is happening". But the problem is, you have no progress indicator or listener on a database statement.

"A direct tracking of progress in the database management system is not possible." Regarding this I was corrected by the other answerer. So there are possibilities to track the progress but these are very database specific. So this is also a way to go if you have only TeraData in mind.

So here are some other possibilities to produce some kind of process feedback:

- Slice your update in multiple steps (n) (if it is possible). You know how many steps you have to go, that would be your 100 percent. Every step should increase your progressbar by 100/n percent.
- This splitting of your SQL is not always a way to go. Therefore you could display a work in progress indicator (an indetermined one).
- You could guess the time to process and build a progressbar on that value, like windows does on file copy.

In every case your database processing should happen in a worker thread (different from EDT), but for sure you are aware of that.

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage the Performance Monitor and Performance Control (PMPC) Open APIs using SQL to monitor the progress of a session as it executes a SQL Statement in Teradata 13 and higher.

**Get Completed Steps, Host, RunVProcNo for all sessions running as user:**

```
SELECT HostID
     , RunVProcNo
     , ReqStepsCompletedCnt
FROM TABLE(MonitorSession(-1,'{username}',  0)) AS T2;
```

You can always obtain the current session for a given connection by running:

`SELECT SESSION;`

With the Session Number in hand you can isolate the number of records returned by the previous `MonitorSession()` call.

**Get Total Number of Steps for SQL being executed:**

```
SELECT MAX(StepNum) AS TotalNumSteps
  FROM TABLE(MonitorSQLSteps({Host},{Session},{RunVProcNo)) AS T1;
```

With those two statements you should be able to track how something is progressing to update a progress bar in the application. `

Comment: I was not aware of this low level possibilities. But is this something you would suggest indeed or did you only show us the possibility?

Comment: The PMPC API is used by the Viewpoint environment to obtain the same information with a low impact on the database environment. It is entirely possible that if the DBA for the environment in question approves of the solution you develop that it can be run in a production environment. The key is to poll the database at a reasonable interval for the type of work being monitored. For example a 60 second interval for monitoring an ad hoc query.